# Select SQL with multiple tables in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, multiple-tables

Two database tables:

1. `Continent` table with `ContinentID` and `ContinentName` columns
2. `City` table with `CityID`, `CityName` and `ContinentName` columns

Situation:

I want to combine the corresponding city to its continent. Like `Europe` (continent) has `Denmark` (country).

However, what's wrong with my SQL statement?

```
select 
    CountryID, CountryName 
from 
    Country 
where 
    Country.ContientID = Contient.ContientID;
```

Comment: Are you sure that Denmark is in your City table? Your question mentions cities, but not countries.

Comment: The tables you mention are `Continent` and `City`, while the rest of the question talks about continents and countries.... please clean up your question and make it be consistent and logic in itself ....

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to join the tables

```
select CountryID, CountryName 
from Country 
inner join Contient on Country.ContientID=Contient.ContientID
```

You were probably trying the old, legacy implicit join syntax which would work like this

```
select CountryID, CountryName 
from Country, Contient
where Country.ContientID=Contient.ContientID
```

but you should not use that any more.